# Custom score function in GridSearchCV: Access to unscaled features, not in the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am using the GridSearchCV package from sklearn in Python and I would like to use it with a custom scoring function. The custom scoring function would need to access variables that are not in the model. The thing is that I am not able to access the variables that are unscaled/unchanged from the training set since they are not included in the model, which uses scaled data, and since gridsearch selects rows at random for each batch. Do you have any idea about how I could deal with that?

I tried to create a scoring function that takes as a parameter the original (unscaled, unchanged) training set. It works but since gridsearch takes only subsets of the training set and the rows are shuffled, I can't "connect" each row with its corresponding value in the original training set. I tried to unscale the data included in the training set but it did not work. I thought about adding the unscaled column I want to the scaled training set but how can I exclude it from the model?

```py
# building pipelines
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
],verbose=True)
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('one_hot_enc',OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore')),
],verbose=True)

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipeline, df_num_reg_attributes),
    ("cat", cat_pipeline, df_cat_attributes)
])

# fitting pipelines
X_train_prepared_reg = full_pipeline.fit_transform(X_res_df)
listColPrepared=np.concatenate((df_num_reg_attributes,full_pipeline.named_transformers_['cat'].named_steps['one_hot_enc'].get_feature_names()))
scalerX_train = full_pipeline.named_transformers_['num'].named_steps['std_scaler']
X_test_prepared_reg = full_pipeline.transform(X_test)
y_train = y_balanced

# scorer
def my_scorer(clf, X, y_true):
    DCWorkCost = 5.00
    OPWorkCost = 2.50
    mergedDataset = pd.DataFrame(data=X,index=np.arange(0,len(X)),columns=listColPrepared)
### this is the column I want -- I tried to unscale the data to access the column but it did not work    
    mergedDataset['Margin'] = scalerX_train.inverse_transform(mergedDataset['Margin'])
    mergedDataset['True'] = y_true
    mergedDataset['Pred'] = clf.predict(X)
 # rest of the scorer.........
    return revenue

# grid search
sgd_clf_cv = SGDClassifier(max_iter=5,tol=-np.infty, random_state=42)
parameters = {'class_weight':({0:.1,1:.9},{0:.2,1:.8},{0:.3,1:.7},{0:.25,1:.75},{0:.15,1:.85},{0:.35,1:.65},{0:.4,1:.6})}
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=sgd_clf_cv, param_grid=parameters, scoring=my_scorer,verbose=10)
grid.fit(X_train_prepared_reg, y_train)
grid.best_estimator_
```

When trying to unscaled the data as shown in the code, I get an error message about not-corresponding shapes.

Comment: You could the `scalerX_train` as a parameter to `sgd_clf_cv` and then it should be accessible in `my_scorer`, e.g. `sgd_clf_cv.scalerX = scalerX_train` and in `my_scorer` use `mergedDataset['Margin'] = clf.scalerX.inverse_transform(mergedDataset['Margin'])`

Comment: That helped a lot thanks. I was able to add the scaler as a property of the model but for some reason, I can't access it in the scorer: it says that "SGDClassifier object has no attribute scalerX". I can access the scaler outside of the scorer though.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps are required to have your own custom scoring function which also has access to another constant object.

1. Your custom score function needs to be passed to [`make_scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer). The format of the scoring function needs to be `def f(y_true, y_predicted)`
2. Your score function needs a third, named parameter where you can your additional object.

In your case the code should look similar to

```
def my_scorer(y_true, y_pred, scaler=None):
    DCWorkCost = 5.00
    OPWorkCost = 2.50
    mergedDataset = pd.DataFrame(data=X, index=np.arange(0, len(y_true)), columns=listColPrepared)
    ### this is the column I want -- I tried to unscale the data to access the column but it did not work    
    mergedDataset['Margin'] = scaler.inverse_transform(mergedDataset['Margin'])
    mergedDataset['True'] = y_true
    mergedDataset['Pred'] = y_pred
   # rest of the scorer.........

    return revenue

...
scalerX_train = full_pipeline.named_transformers_['num'].named_steps['std_scaler']
...
sgd_clf_cv = SGDClassifier(max_iter=5,tol=-np.infty, random_state=42)
...
custom_score = make_scorer(my_scorer, scaler=scalarX_train)
...
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=sgd_clf_cv, param_grid=parameters, scoring=custom_score, verbose=10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I eventually coded the GridSearch myself so I could make it work the way I want it to. However, with your code, would the scaler work? Because I tried before and it said not corresponding shapes. I believe it expects an array of the same size as the one it was trained on, and that won't be the case with GridSearch since it just takes a subset of the rows...

Comment: Please add the code as an answer, perhaps it helps other people searching for the same problem.